# Magento adding Jquery to switch grid and list view with no page refresh

Tags: jquery, list, magento, view, grid

I would like to learn how to add Jquery to switch between grid and list view in magento

The problem is i'm new to magento and i can't find a file where i should hook the Jquery function that handles the switching.

This should be relatively easy to do but in magento never is.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Switch Products View Grid/List Without Refreshing the Page With jQuery](http://www.webcodo.net/switch-products-view-gridlist-without-refreshing-the-page-with-jquery-html-css/)

Then modify the template file and css as needed

```
app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```